# How to turn a list into a square matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

i'm new to python.

I'm trying to figure out how to turn a list like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

into a square matrix which looks something like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
```

without any modules.

Comment: What if the size of the list is not a square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that the length of the list and of the desired matrix are compatible then here an other version;

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

n = 3 # size square matrix

m = []

counter = 0
for i in range(len(l)//3):
    m += [ l[counter* n: counter*n + n ]]
    counter += 1

print(m)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Ops... there was some redundancy (no need at the `counter`) in my answer... here the ultimate version

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

n = 3 # size square matrix
m = []

for i in range(len(l)//3):
    m += [ l[i* n: n*(i+1) ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.reshape`, But make sure the length of the list is a perfect square:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> size = int(np.sqrt(len(d)))
>>> np.reshape(d, (size, size)).tolist()

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

You can also use `list-comprehension` if you don't want to use numpy:

```py
>>> size = int(len(d)**(1/2))
>>> [d[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(d), size)]

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```